# Volume control command

Tags: command-line, remote-access

Is there a way to control volume of a remote system via ssh? we have a media center server and we want to remotely control the volume.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thought it's not a command per-se, `alsamixer` is great for this kind of thing. It's part of the [alsa-utils](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-utils) package

[image]

Comment: super awesome, thanks. that's what we've been looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can also write a bash script using pacmd utility of PulseAudio sound system.

I have found an example script for you: [pulsevol.sh](http://gzn.pastebin.com/wpxZG4Tu)