# Increasing volume beyond 100% using keyboard

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys, volume-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reach over 100% volume with a keyboard shortcut?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51156/how-can-i-reach-over-100-volume-with-a-keyboard-shortcut)

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I saw, it is possible to increase volume beyond 100% using sound control GUI.

I set keyboard shortcut to increase volume, but it increases volume upto 100% only.

How can I increase volume beyond 100%  using keyboard shortcut as I can do with GUI?