# Sound panel missing in gnome tweaks

Tags: gnome, sound, 18.04, gnome-tweak-tool

`gnome-tweaks` is missing the sound panel in my installation of Ubuntu 18.04. (which I need to enable sound over-amplification)
I have `gsettings-desktop-schemas` version 3.28 installed.
I am using vanilla gnome instead of the default "unitified" gnome of Ubuntu 18.04.
How do I get the sound panel back and is there any other way to use enable sound over-amplification?

Comment: On my Ubuntu 18.04 the sound panel is located in gnome-control-center, not in gnome-tweaks. Could it be that you're looking in the wrong place?

Comment: @FrankvanWensveen I think there is supposed to be a sound option in tweak tools. I do have the sound panel in gnome-control-center too but it lacks the option to over amplify the sound. Upon further reading I found out that this option apparently can be turned on from the sound panel within gnome-tweaks (which I lack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having Googled this for you, I [find](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1755982): "There is a toggle switch in GNOME Tweaks but that toggle isn't exposed in Ubuntu because

1. It duplicates the functionality already in the GNOME Settings app
   on Ubuntu
2. The Ubuntu feature still uses a different gsettings
   key, in part because there are still patches for this feature that
   GNOME hasn't reviewed yet (for gnome-shell in particular).

So offhand, it doesn't look like you have this opton in Gnome Tweaks on Ubuntu 18.04.

Google also led me [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180894/is-there-any-way-to-boost-the-audio-output-of-ubuntu-12-04-lts) and the suggestion to use

```
pactl -- set-sink-volume 0 250%
```

(for 250% amplification) still works fine on 18.04. See "man pactl" for more info.

Comment: Yeah I saw the `pactl` way when I googled this too. I was hoping for a way to get this some way in `gnome-control-center`. Well anyways, guess I will have to make-do with `pactl` until Gnome does something. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my Ubuntu (18.04) system this command worked:

> pactl -- set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ 250%