# Is it possible to control the recording if Audacity is running in the background?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, audacity, audio-recording

I would like to record audio while Audacity is running in the background, e.g. because I am focused on another window. Is it possible to control the start and stop of a recording using global keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: You could create a keyboard shortcut which runs [an `xdotool` command which sends a keystroke to a specific window](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87831) -- the Audacity window, in this case.

Comment: Hi orschiro, just curious, but us any of the options usable in your situation?

Comment: @JacobVlijm I forgot to mark the best answer, sorry. I chose yours because I like its simplicity. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Does Audacity have cli options?

Unfortunately, looking into `man audacity`, does not show any interesting or relevant options:

```
OPTIONS
       -help     display a brief list of command line options

       -version  display the audacity version number

       -test     run  self  diagnostics  tests  (only  present  in development
                 builds)

       -blocksize nnn
                 set the audacity block size for writing files to disk to  nnn
                 bytes
```

### However...

***simply pausing/continuing Audacity from cli works exactly similarly to pausing/continuing recording***

I tested pausing Audacity as a process, with the commands `kill -stop <pid>` and `kill -cont <pid>`. It did the job perfectly; it stopped recording immediately, resuming immediately when the process was continued. Even after 6 or seven hours, it stops/resumes recording right away with these commands.

Adding the two commands to shortcut keys does *exactly* what you describe.

#### How to use

Add the following two commands to shortcut keys:

```
/bin/bash -c "kill -stop $(pgrep audacity)"
```

...to stop (pause) recording, and

```
/bin/bash -c "kill -cont $(pgrep audacity)"
```

...to resume, and you have your own shortcut keys to start/stop (actually pause) recording.

Only the initial *starting* of the recording needs to be done via the Audacity GUI.

#### Adding to shortcut keys

Choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the two commands above to two different shortcut keys.

#### Extending options

Of course we can extend options, e.g.

```
/bin/bash -c "kill -cont $(pgrep audacity) && notify-send Recording"
```

and

```
/bin/bash -c "kill -stop $(pgrep audacity) && notify-send Stopped"
```

[image]

...to show a notification on the current state, or even make a panel icon to show the current state. Anything is possible

---

### Additionally, a toggle script, as requested in a comment

The script below will toggle recording. Add it to either a shortcut key or launch it in any other way.

The script reads the current process state from the file `/proc/<pid>/status`, and decides what the targeted state should therefore be.

Additionally, the script notifies the user what happens in a notification (using `notify-send`).

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess

try:
    pid = subprocess.check_output(["pgrep", "audacity"]).decode("utf-8").strip()
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    pass
else:
    state = "(stopped)" in open("/proc/"+pid+"/status").read()
    if state == True:
        cmd = ["kill", "-cont", pid]; msg = "Recording"
    else:
        cmd = ["kill", "-stop", pid]; msg = "Pausing"
    subprocess.Popen(cmd)
    subprocess.Popen(["notify-send", msg])
```

#### To use it

- Simply copy it into an empty file, save it as `toggle_record.py`
- Test run it with the command:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/toggle_record.py
  ```
- If all works fine add it to a shortcut key as explained earlier in the answer.

Comment: Sending stop signal isnt always good for GUI applications. In case of firefox, if it is stopped for a while it crashes, at least in my experience. But yeah, that is the best option available so far

Comment: @Serg, yeah, that's why I tested it for a while. until now I didn't get a single error :)

Comment: how long was it stopped ?

Comment: Run it for a couple hours, let me know if it works

Comment: Hi @Serg 7 hours later, it started right away. We may assume it works.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. What about adding both commands in one bash script that toggles between the two commands with the same keyboard shortcut?

Comment: @JacobVlijm thanks it will save me a lot of time :)

Comment: Hi @JasonStack as rquested, see my edited answer :)

Answer (score 4):

#### Can Audacity be controlled when its window not in focus ?

In theory, yes, since it has a [scripting module](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Scripting_Module), which apparently can be used with Perl scripting language, but as of right now I've not seen one made, so there is potential for Perl-skilled developers to write one.

But as it is, the answer to your question is "no".

#### arecord Script

What's great about open source community is that there's always an alternative. In this case, `arecord` , which works from command-line. What you see below is a very quick script I've made, which is intended to be bound to a keyboard shortcut. Usage is simple: press key combination - recording starts, and press it again to stop recording.

What's "hard-coded" in this script is the default `wav` type of recording and `~/Music/records` folder. Users are free to edit this script as they like to use their own options/filetypes/locations, etc. Please consult `arecord` man page for additional options.

Eventually I plan rewriting this script in Python, which will allow more fine-grained control of user's directories, add command-line options, perhaps other things. As for now, this does 75% of the job needs to be done.

Below is the source code of the script which is also available on my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep/blob/master/audio_record.sh). Standard  rules for creating and using scripts apply: ensure it has executable permissions and is stored in your `~/bin` folder

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# Author: Serg Kolo
# Date: Dec 1, 2016
# Purpose: simple script for recording audio with arecord
# Written for: https://askubuntu.com/q/855893/295286

record_audio()
{
    # Set up some variables to control arecord here
    # Please remember to quote the variables
    # and pay attention to slashes in file paths

    filetype="wav"
    filename="record_$(date +%H_%M_%m_%d_%Y)"
    directory="$HOME/Music/recordings/"

    if ! [ -d "$directory" ];
    then
        mkdir "$directory"
    fi

    # This part will initiate recording of timestamped
    # please see arecord's man page for other options
    notify-send "Recording started"
    exec arecord -t "$filetype" "$directory""$filename"."$filetype"
}

main()
{
    if pgrep -f "arecord" ;
    then
       pkill -f "arecord" && notify-send "Recording stopped"
    else
       record_audio
    fi
}

main "$@"
```

#### additional information:

- [Setting custom keyboard shortcuts](https://askubuntu.com/a/591605/295286)
- [How to make a script executable](https://askubuntu.com/q/229589/295286)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can use a combination of **a script**, **xdotool**, **wmctrl** and **Ubuntu's hotkey**.

First create the file to select the recording window and send the command key to that window.

Then assign a hotkey to activate the script.

### The Script

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Specify the Window running your recording by running 
# "./hkrecord.sh getwindowid" from the command line.
# Alternatively you can edit the ~/recordfile and place your own string.  This
# first line of the fie will be used 

# Ensure you have the following "xdotool" and "wmctrl" installed.

recordfile="$HOME/recordfile"

getwindowid(){
    windowid=$(wmctrl -lp | awk '{$2=$3=$4=":"; print $0}'| awk -F: \
'{print $1"\n"$4}' | zenity --list --column="No" --height=800 --width=1000 \
--column="Select your choice" \
--text="Text above column(s)" --hide-column=1 --title="My menu" 2>/dev/null)
    [[ "$windowid" ]] && sed -i "1i @$windowid" $recordfile || \
echo "No Window selected"
    exit
}

if [ ! $# -eq 0 ]; then
    if [[ "x$1" == *"get"* ]]; then     
        echo "Getting the window id"
        getwindowid
        exit
    fi
fi

recordwindow="$(head -n1 $recordfile)"

if [ "$(echo $recordwindow | egrep '@0x')" ]; then
    windowid=$(echo $recordwindow | sed "s/\@//")
else
    windowid=$(echo $(wmctrl -lp|egrep -i $recordwindow)|head -n1|\
awk '{print $1}')
    echo "$windowid|$recordfwindow"  # debug line... can be commented out.
fi

echo "Using WindowID: $windowid" # debug line... can be commented out.

if [ -z $windowid ]; then
    espeak "Can't locate specified window!"
    espeak "Exiting..."
    exit
fi

xdotool key --window $windowid p
```

Save the script to a convenient area such as `/usr/local/bin/hkrecord.sh`

### Assign the hotkey

First run the script from the commandline as a quick test.  Then assign the **global keyboard shortcut**.  To specify the window (needed only one time) run:

```
$ ./hkrecord.sh getwindow
```

Running `hkrecord.sh` without an argument will control the recording.

Go into `System Settings` ->  `keyboard` and add a custom Keyboard Shortcut.  Pick a hotkey that won't conflict with your foreground program.  I use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.

This is the configuraton for the **Custom Shortcut**:

```
Name:        Hotkey Record
Command:     /usr/local/bin/hkrecord.sh
```

I placed the instructions as comments in the script file.

As an added benefit, the same Global Hotkey can be used for **pausing playback**.  I use this system as a dictaphone to write from my recorded notes.

I tried to make the script very simple to be easy to understand and customize.  Thoroughly tested, it will work seamlessly.

*Note: Thanks goes out to don_crissti and and George_Vasiliou (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/328548/81664) for helping me with the GUI for selecting the record window.*

Comment: In theory a nice option, but currently not working on my Unity /16.04). I believe `xdotool`'s `xdotool key --window` (or actually the way you search for the window) is likely to catch a cold.  If I add `echo $windowid` to the script, I get 7 (!) different window -id's, which obviously is false (Unity), and the script fails totally. Whenever I look for the corresponding window -id in `wmctrl` however and run the command directly,  it works. I'd suggest looking for the appropriate window by `pid` and using `wmctrl`. Add a notification and you have a winner.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I updated the script about the same time you posted.  I added the option to isolate only one window if more than one window is found.  Be sure to have a much of the Window tittle to distinguish it from similar tittle windows.

Comment: I mean you need to find the window from `wmctrl -lp`, looking for a match with `pgrep audacity`. That is a 100% working match.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I'm noticing that **xdotool** isn't recognizing the window by the name "Audacity".  Use the save option to save the project or file to a unique name.  I already added this information to the answer.

Comment: really not necessary, just look for the line in `wmctrl -lp` in which the pid of audacity is found, always works if there is a single window.

Comment: I thought that was handled.  If it can't find the window it will exit with an audible prompt.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I immediately removed the comment, but apparantly too late :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49501/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-jacob-vlijm).