# How do I link my keyboard keys to control audio AND to display the according UI?

Tags: sound, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have a new keyboard and could not control audio on my system at first. Then I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181341/how-do-i-set-a-custom-keyboard-shortcut-to-control-volume) that let me create a shortcut to edit the volume. This somewhat works, however I would still like to have the according UI (see attached image) to show up as well. Does anyone know of a fix that includes this part of audio changing as well?

[image]

Comment: Not a helpful answer, but I think this should work out of the box, i.e. not require any change on your part.

Comment: @Jos, no, using volume commands will not automatically pop up this graphic. Will need something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the shortcut that you have setup remove them and then

Go to settings -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Under Sound and Media

You will find Volume Down , Volume Up and other shortcuts disabled by default you can select your shortcut key here and it will work with along with the GUI

[These Settings here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOht9.png)

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for, thank you!