# keyboard shortcut to "Output volume" in sound control

Tags: 12.10, volume-control

I sometimes want to increase the output volume on my laptop beyond 100 %. In order to do so I need to open "Sound" in "System Settings". I would like to set a keyboard shortcut to do that. I found out that I can set a custum shortcut in System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts with the command "gnome-control-center sound", which will bring up "Sound". So far that works well, but there is a little optimization that I would like but cannot figure out. The problem is this: When I use the shortcut to open "Sound", the focus is not on "Output volume". So before I can modify the output volume with the arrow keys, I need to either click on output volume or hit the Tab key five times, thus moving the focus to output volume. My question is this: Is there something that I can add to the command "gnome-control-center sound" so that the focus is moved to "Output volume" automatically, for example something equivalent to "hit Tab key five times"?

Thanks in advance for your help!
Wolfhart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers to your question exist here:

[How can I reach over 100% volume with a keyboard shortcut?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51156/how-can-i-reach-over-100-volume-with-a-keyboard-shortcut)

Personally I prefer this way:

Open the sound settings and with sound settings opened , open also a terminal.

Then try the command below

```
pacmd set-sink-volume 0 80000
```

Probably you will see the sound increased further than 100%. Use other values than 80000 until find what serves you.

Now create the shortcuts that you need.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! I had missed the other post. Since I don't want to set the volume to a fixed value but increase it gradually I used the command `pactl set-sink-volume 0 +10%` (mentioned in one of the replies to the other post) for my shortcut. What took me a little while was to find the corresponding command to decrease the volume. Simply changing plus into minus does not work, two extra dashes are needed: `pactl -- set-sink-volume 0 -10%`